# Como obter as características do dispositivo Android

Tags: android

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento Android com a plataforma SDK e gostaria de saber como obter as características do dispositivo do usuário.

Ex: IMEI, versão do Android, modelo do aparelho, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa informação pode ser obtida recorrendo à classe [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)
Ela contém vários campos estáticos contendo informação sobre o dispositivo.

Exemplos:

```
String produto = Build.PRODUCT;
String modelo = Build.MODEL; 
String fabricante = Build.MANUFACTURER;
```

Em termos da versão do Android recorra à classe [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

Exemplos:

```
String codeName = Build.VERSION.CODENAME;
String incremental = Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL; 
String realese = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

Um dos campos mais utilizados da classe [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) é `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` que, em conjunto com a classe [Build.VERSION_CODES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html), nos permite verificar de forma fácil a versão instalada do Android SDK.

Exemplo:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

     // o código aqui só será executado nas versões 
     // HONEYCOMB ou superior
}
```